# Unexpected output of the main function by repeated call

Tags: c

I am executing a code written in C and it is giving unexpected result which I could not able to figure it out. Why is the value of I printing five times?

**Here is the code below:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    static int  i = 0;
    static int count =0;
    if (i<5){
        i++;
        main();
        printf("%d\n",i);
        ++count;
        printf("%d\n",count);
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
5
1
5
2
5
3
5
4
5
5
```

Comment: `void main()` is horribly non-standard C. Get in the habit of writing standard compliant code. `int main(void)`.

Comment: Ok,but using int, also the result remains sam

Comment: My comment has nothing to do with the (correct) result. Use a debugger to trace through the code.

Comment: There's nothing unexpected from this code. A better question from you is what did you expect that the output would be?

Comment: why the value of i is printing 5 times.

Comment: Step through it with a debugger,

Comment: I am not getting the perfect explanation buddy @jhonny

Comment: Though this is not recommended recursively calling `main()`, since `i` is static, keeping its value, subsequent calls to print i after the recursion of main has ended would be 5.

Comment: Nobody owes anyone an explanation here. If you want help on SO, do the required work and use a debugger.

Comment: The value of `i` is printed 5 times for the same reason that the value of `count` is printed 5 times — which is because the `main()` function is called 5 times by the code shown, plus once from the startup code, and one of those calls finds that `i < 5` is not true which terminates the recursion.

Comment: As stated by @JonathanLeffler, once the recursion stops, then 'i' is 5' then `main()` is no longer being called  The code successively steps out of the recursion. At each step, the code following the recursive call to `main()` is executed.  So the value contained in 'i' is printed (5) then 'count' is incremented and printed I.E. 'value in i, value in count'  (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5).  if you had labeled each value being printed with where that value came from, it would be much more obvious as to what is happening

Comment: BTW: it is a very poor programming practice to call `main()`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the output.

- You first set i = 0.
- the first if(i<5) passes, so i is being incremented (note: i++ means i is still 4, but when its next used the value is 5).
- Call to main, the static variable i and count keep their values as static variables are not being overwritten, that way the programm passes if(i<5) until i = 5, then if(i<5) returns false and the fifth call to main ends abruptly.
- Since in the fifth call to main nothing happens, the value of i is now still 4, but since you incremented i via i++, i in printf() is now 5 as this is the time i is being used first after the incremention. Printf shows:

  ```
  5
  ```
- count is getting incremented via ++count (++count means the value is instantly incremented, so count is now 1). Printf shows:

  ```
  1
  ```
- Now the recursive loop ends. For each "level" the line

  ```
  main();
  ```

  is done calling, so the next line is

  ```
  printf("%d\n", i);
  ```

  since we never change the value of i anymore (because for all "levels" we already incremented i up to 5), the console shows us 5 times the value of 5 for variable i.
- The only thing we still change though is the variable count. Since the variable count is still being incremented AFTER the recursive call to main, count still adds up to 5. So the output looks like this:

  ```
  5 (i, level 5)
  1 (count, level 5)
  5 (i, level 4)
  2 (count, level 4)
  5 (i, level 3)
  3 (count, level 3)
  5 (i, level 2)
  4 (count, level 2)
  5 (i, level 1)
  5 (count, level 1)
  ```
- When count reached 5, we reached the "top" level of our recursive call stack again and the programm ends.