# Recursion and static variables

Tags: c, recursion

So I was preparing for an entrance exam here in India when I came across this piece of C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    static int i = 4;
    if (--i) {
        main();
        printf("%d", i);
    }
}
```

I thought the `printf` statement never gets executed and the output will be blank.
But I saw the answer to be `0000` and that this happens due to the `static` keyword with the `int`.

Can anyone explain why the printf executes or is that guy wrong?

Comment: Calling `main` leads to undefined behavior, at least in C++. This code could set your machine on fire if it wanted.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag, because your code is either C++ **or** C. and since your code is using `printf`, and you say it's C, the C++ tag is wrong.

Comment: You could try running it and see what happens, however I agree with @AndyG this code is terrible.  Good on you for questioning it though and not just blindly accepting this code was right.  Shows critical thinking.

Comment: I mean, even if it *was* legal to call main from itself (like it is with any other function, basically), this would not be a terrible example of recursion.

Comment: It is allowed in C

Comment: 'main' legalities aside, That guy is right. Once i hits zero the code stops recursing and returns to the next statement. The static variable means that it isn't stacked hence it remains at zero.

Comment: yeah he told this is bad code. this was supposed to teach us about static. Im still so confused about this.

Comment: Entrance exam - to teach about `static`? something is not adding up...

Comment: the `if (--i)` decrements i before the test, and if i is not zero goes inside the block and calls `main` which is legal in C.  The second (and each subsequent time) main is entered, the static variable i is not re-initialized.  So, it really is 3 the second time.  Once i is decremented all the way down to zero, the if test returns false, and the block is skipped and the most deeply recursed main returns.  That's when each `printf` statement is executed.

Comment: Remarkably similar to [Unexpected output of the `main()` function by repeated calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393083/).  The  printing is different, and there's an extra local variable that is printed too, but…

Comment: @MarcusMüller, if a question goes for both C and C++ it would be very appropriate to run both tags. Now you're denying all C++ only experts to see this question and possible answer it...

Comment: i is a static variable, which means it's lifetime is the entire run of the program, the recursion happens before the prinft, so on the first run i=4, it will be lowered to 3 and then main() is called again, i will be set to '2', and main() is called, i is set to '1', main is called, then --i=0, so the function ends, we then come back from the recursion and '0' is printed... then we go back from another recursion and another '0' is printed, etc, etc, 'till you're left with '0000'. So the guy is right

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why the printf executes or is that guy wrong?

Because `main` returns.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45445983/6660678) writes out the logic, but I see that you are still asking this in comments.  So I'm going to say the same thing in a different way and hope that it is clearer to you.

Because the variable is `static`, prior to the first call, the variable is declared and set to 4.  Because it is `static`, the same variable will be used every time.  It just skips over the declaration and initialization if called again (or likely even the first time, as `static` variables can be allocated before running).

In the first call, the variable is decremented to 3.  3 is a truthy value, so we do the block of the `if`.  This calls `main` recursively.

In this second call, the variable is decremented to 2.  2 is still truthy in C.  We call `main` recursively again.

In this third call, the variable is decremented to 1.  1 is still truthy.  We recurse to `main` again.

In this fourth call, the variable is decremented to 0.  0 is falsey in C.  We do not enter the block of the `if`.  We do not recurse.  We do not print.  There's nothing left to do in this call to `main`.  It returns at the end.

Now we're back in the third call.  We just returned from the call to `main`.  We are still inside the `if` block.  The next statement is a `printf`.  The value of the variable is now 0.  So we print a 0.  Nothing left to do, we return at the end.

Now we're back in the second call.  Still 0, so we print another 0 and return.

Now we're back in the first call.  Still 0, so we print another 0 and return.

We printed 0 three times, so 000

As you note, on the way down, we don't print.  We print on the way back up.  By that time, the variable is 0.  And we enter the then block of the `if` three times.  So we recurse and then print three times.

When you call a function recursively, you don't eliminate the previous call.  You put it on the stack.  When done, you come back to the place where you left and continue with the next statement.

You may want to think about how the following three pieces of code will react differently:

```
void recurse() {
    static int i = 4;
    if (--i) {
        recurse();
        printf("%d", i);
    }
}
```

Prints 000 when called the first time.  Probably prints nothing on a second call and crashes.  If you have a larger stack than the `int` size (which seems unlikely but is not impossible in theory), then it would print many 0s.  E.g. for an eight bit `int`, it would print 255 0s (one for each possible non-zero value).

```
void recurse(int i) {
    if (--i) {
        recurse(i);
        printf("%d", i);
    }
}
```

Will print 123 if called as `recurse(4)`.  As a parameter, we are dealing with a different `i` each time the function is called.

```
void recurse(int i) {
    if (--i) {
        printf("%d", i);
        recurse(i);
    }
}
```

Prints 321 if called as `recurse(4)`.  Printing on the way down rather than when coming back up.

```
void recurse(int i) {
    printf("%d", i);
    if (--i) {
        recurse(i);
    }
}
```

Prints 4321 if called as `recurse(4)`.  It prints on the way down, rather than the way up.

```
void recurse() {
    static int i = 4;
    printf("%d", i);
    if (--i) {
        recurse();
    }
}
```

Will print 4321.  We're printing on the way down, not the way up.  Note how the parameter and the `static` variable give the same result this way.  However, if this is called a second time, it will do nothing.  The parameter would print the same thing again.

```
void recurse() {
    int i = 4;
    if (--i) {
        recurse();
        printf("%d", i);
    }
}
```

Loops forever.  Without the `static` we make a new `i` each time.  This will run until it overloads the stack and crashes.  No output because it never makes it to the `printf`.

The easiest way to check this is to go somewhere like ideone.com and run the code.  Asking why it prints something is reasonable for this site.  But asking what it prints is something that you should answer yourself.

Comment: Thank you man. That clears everything

Comment: Just a note: in that first block, on the second run, something does happen. And that something will probably blow out the stack. (If `i` is 0, `--i` is -1.)

Answer (score 31):

In the context of the question being about recursion, it will print out "000" (I don't know why the answer shows 4 zeros because with '--i' decrement happens before assignment). If you unroll the calls you get:

```
if (--i) { //i == 3
    if (--i) { //i == 2
        if (--i) { //i == 1
            if (--i) { //i == 0
                // rest does not get evaluated since the condition is false
            }
            printf("%d", i); // i is 0 now
        }
        printf("%d", i); //i is still 0
    }
    printf("%d", i); //i is still 0
}
```

However like most have mentioned this code sucks and I would advise you never consider this level of sloppiness for any software you write.

Comment: Technically this is the answer to his question but it drifted away I guess

Comment: Maybe the "answer" shows four 0s because *they* don't understand their own "entrance exam"... :v

Answer (score 22):

It *is* legal to recurse on `main` in C<sup>*</sup> (although *why would you*?)

Additionally, C11 (5.1.2.2.1) states:

> It shall be defined with a return type of `int` ... [or] If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the
>   termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

(C++ states that the return type must be `int`)

So this portion of the code is actually standard-compliant, but the actual return is implementation-defined (thanks @chux)

> Can anyone explain why the printf executes or is that guy wrong?

If you're compiling C with a C++ compiler, guy is wrong. Otherwise the code will compile.

Now that this is out of the way, the `printf` will indeed execute because the `static` variable is only ever initialized once, as per 6.2.4/3

> An object whose identifier is declared [...]with the
>   storage-class specifier `static` has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire
>   execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program
>   startup

<sup>*It is definitely NOT legal in C++. From [basic.start.main]:
 "The function main shall not be used within a program". There's a lot of C++ asides in this answer because the question was originally tagged as C++ and the information is useful</sup>

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple problems in this code:

- `<stdio.h>` is not included, calling `printf("%d", i);` has undefined behavior.
- The prototype for `main` without arguments is `int main(void)`.  Defining `main` as `void main()` is non portable and incorrect on some platforms.  Always use the Standard prototypes for `main` and return a valid exit status for good style.
- It is bad style to call the `main` function recursively in C, and it has undefined behavior in C++.

Ignoring the fact that undefined behavior means anything can happen, including Indian firms using horrendous programming tests, the reason the program prints `0000` is you probably mistyped the `if (i--)` test or misplaced the braces from memory, or the guy is plain wrong. The `main` function calls itself recursively 3 times decrementing the same `i` variable each time until it becomes `0` and each instance prints the value of `i`, namely `0` before it returns to its caller, including the initial invocation of `main()`.

`static int i = 4;` inside a function defines a global variable `i` with an initial value of `4` that can only be accessed inside the block where it is defined.  All recursive instances of `main` access the same variable.

Comment: I can't see how omitting the header would make calling `printf` undefined behavior. It seems to me it would require a compilation error (if no other declaration of `printf` is found). Calling a function that is not declared is not UB.

Comment: I just didnt add printf here just cuz I thought it was implied. Let me edit it

Comment: Calling a function that is not declared used to make an implicit definition for it.  `printf("%d", i);` would use an implicit declaration as `int printf(char *, int);` which is incompatible with the actual definition.  Hence undefined behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: If the declaration and the code don't agree on calling conventions, number of args, return types, etc, you're in trouble.

Comment: "Defining main as void main() is incorrect." is allowable per 5.1.2.2.1 1 "or in some other implementation-defined manner." and so is ID behavior.  Yet it  is unnecessarily so as `int main()` is unquestionably OK - and shorter too.

Comment: @chux: yes you are correct, although I suspect *other implementation-defined manner* mostly refers to the extra `envp` argument described in annex J: ***J.5.1 Environment arguments** In a hosted environment, the main function receives a third argument, `char *envp[]`, that points to a null-terminated array of pointers to char, each of which points to a string that provides information about the environment for this execution of the program (5.1.2.2.1).*

Comment: @chqrlie Agree about other _useful_ implementation-defined manners.  IMO, `void main(.....` should live with `gets()`.

Answer (score 6):

Abstracting from the quality and the name of this function.

All `static` variables are initialised only one time during the program startup, and remain its value.

When the startup routine calls main for the first time the variable `i` has value 4. Then you decrease its value to 3 and call main again. This time the value of `i` is 3 Then you decrease its value to 2 ......

Comment: yeah but since we call main() before printf, the printf never gets executed right. Might be the case if printf is outside the if statement. But printf is inside the if and after the main() call